# I just bought a new Cube Hyde Bike

Tags: tire, innertube

I just bought a new cube hyde 2017 bike and I'm not the biggest fan of the stock tyres that came with the bike. I mainly use it on roads and urban areas so I would prefer a more low profile tyre. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I fear your question will be flagged as answers would be opinion based rather than factual and objective.

I recommend deciding what width tire you want (note that your rims will have a minimum tire width they can accommodate though), read some reviews (there are plenty online) and decide what you think is best for the amount you are prepared to pay.

---

Update: personally for road use I'd go for a tire in the 35-28 mm range that gets a decent or 'good value' review and is in the middle price tier. You will probably be good with a wire bead tire, but you can bump up to a kevlar bead if you want.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, your bike came with Schwalbe Big Apples. These are popular and good tires and I wouldn't spend money to replace them.

Tires are one of the most important parts of your bike and in my opinion, you should get the best available. This can decide if you come down on a wet, slippery road or not.
With the Marathon Supremes, I was riding behind a guy on a steep wet road downhill. He on his good racing tires was slipping several times, while I wasn't even near to the limits of my tires.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here.  You might consider answering something more like "medium-price touring tyres would be better than stock tyres used to complete a bike."